# How to convert cumulative data to daily data for multiple-indexes in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataset of following form -

```
date      code     A B C
20-02-01  box1     1 2 1
20-02-02  box1     2 2 1
20-02-03  box1     3 2 1
20-02-01  box2     2 1 1
20-02-04  box3     4 2 1
20-02-05  box3     5 2 1
20-02-06  box3     7 2 1
```

The A,B,C columns represents cumulative values over dates given in first column for each box. 
Now I want to create another row that can find daily increase in *A* w.r.t. each box in python. 
For eg. final should be -

```
date      code     A B C D
20-02-01  box1     1 2 1 1
20-02-02  box1     2 2 1 1
20-02-03  box1     3 2 1 1
20-02-01  box2     2 1 1 2 
20-02-04  box3     4 2 1 4 
20-02-05  box3     5 2 1 1 
20-02-06  box3     7 2 1 2
```

How can I find difference in A based on two indexes(date, code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the dataframe by `code`, then using [`.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) on column `A` you can find the daily increase in column `A` by using the combination of functions [`.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), [`.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) & [`.abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html):

```
df['D'] = (
    df.groupby(['code'])['A']
    .transform(lambda s: s.sub(s.shift().fillna(0)).abs())
)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
       date  code  A  B  C  D
0  20-02-01  box1  1  2  1  1
1  20-02-02  box1  2  2  1  1
2  20-02-03  box1  3  2  1  1
3  20-02-01  box2  2  1  1  2
4  20-02-04  box3  4  2  1  4
5  20-02-05  box3  5  2  1  1
6  20-02-06  box3  7  2  1  2
```